# Adress certain numeric-variables depending on number after last backslash

Tags: r, dataframe, time, backslash

In my data-frame I have a column that consists of dates. Those dates I have converted to DD/MM/YY-notation, now I'm wondering whether or not I can address only those lines in my frame, for which the YY of my date is equal to a specific number. Say for example I only want to look at lines for which the year is 18, but that includes all days and months. Example:

values <- (3, 4, 5, 2)

dates <- ("6/7/19", "3/5/18", "12/12/18", "5/2/12")

frame <- data.frame(values, dates)

Now, for example frame[dates == "3/5/18", "values"] would give me 4, but I'm wondering, if I can use a certain command to target all strings which have 18 in place of the year in the bracket. Also, later I want to create a subframe that contains only those lines (out of 400.000 datapoints) in which the year specified was 18, but I'm guessing that will work once I have understood how to address that variable.

Thanks for an answers in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Reproducible example please!!

Comment: Hey, I tried coming up with a comprehensible example, I hope it suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using package `lubridate` as it has conveniant functions to turn a timestamp into a `Date`-format. Use `dmy()` (short for day-month-year) to convert your timestamps. Here is an example using `dplyr` syntax:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(
  date = dmy(c("19/01/18", "12/05/18", "30/03/19")),
  dummydata = paste0("dummy", 1:3)
)

DF %>% 
  filter(year(date) == 2018)
```

Comment: Hey, sorry, I just saw your answer and therefore couldn't consider it before my edit. When I got the data, the dates were completely unformatted with some being in 12-13-2018-notation and some being in 7/13/18 and even some in 07/13/2018, I used gsub() command to get it to a unitary format which in my case is know 7/3/09 (single letter for date and month and double notation with zero for year). Now I'm thinking I probably won't be able to convert to date-format, anymore.

Comment: as long as they are d-m-y or dd-mm-yyyy or even dd-MMM-yyyy, lubridate will take good care of them. Having dates as dates is the best decision you can make when you have that kind of data.

Comment: Exacty. `lubridate` is designed to handle situations like this. In your case you will need to use the function `mdy()` (month-day-year format separators usualy dont matter).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your question is without an example. If I understand it right, you want to extract year from the `TimeStamp` and use that to filter rows from the `DataFrame`. You can extract the year from `TimeStamp` by using year.

```
Example: year(now())
            [1] 2019
```

Comment: I have just edited my question so that it includes an example.